# How to pass rest of the properties which are not defined as props to a component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

For instance, I am writing a component, `CustomButton`, but I don't want to declare all possible props such as class, title, etc. or pass all events.
In **React** we can get the rest of the props and use them like the below-

```
const { text= 'Open', ...rest } = props
<button {...rest}>{text}</button>

<custom-button text="Open" title="Open" class="w-100"></custom-button>
```

How is this possible in Vue?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass it using *fall through($attrs) attribute* as below:

```
<button v-bind="$attrs">{{text}}</button>
```

Also you can have all event handlers for the custom-button with assigning $listners like this:

```
<button v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs">{{text}}</button>
```

Therefore you can use custom-button component like this:

```
<custom-button text="Open" title="Open" class="w-100" @click="handler" @mousemove="handler"></custom-button>
```

Comment: $listeners is needed for Vue 2 only.